# Laravel merge multiple rows as multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

So I have four tables:

- experiments (tables) - id
- feature_classes (columns) - id, experiment_id, title
- entities (rows) - id, experiment_id
- features (cells) - id, entity_id, feature_class_id, value

I need to construct a table from these four tables.

I tried this:

```
$experiment_id = $request->input('experiment_id');
    $feature_classes = FeatureClass::where('experiment_id', $experiment_id)->select('title', 'id')->get();

    $select = [
        'entities.id',
        'entities.prediction',
        'entities.result'
    ];

    foreach ($feature_classes as $f) {
        $select[] = $f->id . ".value AS " .$f->id;
    }

    $entities = DB::table('entities')
        ->where('experiment_id', $experiment_id);

    foreach ($feature_classes as $f) {
        $entities = $entities->leftJoin('features AS ' . $f->id, function ($join) use ($f){
            $join->on($f->id . '.entity_id', '=', 'entities.id')
                ->where($f->id . '.feature_class_id', $f->id);
        });
    }

    return $entities
        ->select($select)
        ->get();
```

But my efforts are rewarded with this error message `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1 ? left join`features`as`2`on`2`.`entity_id`=`entities`.`id`and`2`.`fe' at line 1 (SQL: select `entities`.`id`, `entities`.`prediction`, `entities`.`result`, `1`.`value` as `1`, `2`.`value` as `2` from `entities` left join `features` as `1` on `1`.`entity_id` = `entities`.`id` and `1`.`feature_class_id` 1 left join `features` as `2` on `2`.`entity_id` = `entities`.`id` and `2`.`feature_class_id` 2 where `experiment_id` = 1) `

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that you shouldn't have to. You should approach this by adding the many to many relations in the model only, then using eloquent to do all the rest. For example, in the features model:

```
public function Classes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes', 'feature_classes', 'feature_class_id', 'id');
}
```

Then something similar that defines the relationship between classes and entities linking by experiment_id. Then you should be able to access the data you need by using the native eloquent features like

```
$entities = Features::where('experiment_id', $experiment_id)->Classes->Entities;

return $entities
```

More information here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: What do you mean by 'App\Classes'?

Comment: The model to which it relates... its more detailed in the documentation

Comment: 1. `Feature` doesn't have many to many relationship with `FeatureClass`. 2. `Feature` doesn't have `experiment_id` column. 3. `FeatureClass` is not directly related to `Entity`. 4. Even if you did get relations right, I'm sure your answer would return only data from `entities` table, without `feature` table data and feature description from  `feature_classes` table

Comment: I don't know the intricacies of your application, nor the data structure but the intermediate data can be accessed via eloquent as well. Good luck!

Comment: Accessing information was not the question. The question is how to get into a single table from SQL or 2D array the most effective way without iterating through all the records.